# Eliminate any kind of space between tags

Tags: jquery

How to eliminate any kind of space between tags with jQuery?

This works: `replace(/&nbsp;/g, '')`
But I am looking for something more generic that could find any kind of space. I leave commented in the snipped some of the things that I tried and does not work. I would appreciate if someone could explain why these option does not eliminate space between tags and a way to do so.

```js
$("#tot").click(function() {
  
var content = $('#tot').html();
//var clean = content.replace(/\s+/g, ''); //no
//var clean = content.replace(/\n|\r/g, ""); //no
//var clean = content.replace(/ \>[\n\t ]+\< /g, ''); //no
var clean = content.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''); // yes but it is not any space 
$('#tot').html( clean );
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tot" contenteditable="true"> 
    <h1> Some title </h1>
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    
    <h2> Some h2 </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you are trying to do some html minification (more on that on google). I was assigned such as task recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\s` stands for "whitespace" in regex. try using `\s*` to replace all whitespace. i'm not sure if that will capture `&nbsp;`s though, so you can do this:

```
var clean = content.replace(/(&nbsp|\s)*;/g, '')
```

To replace all whitespace or `&nbsp;`s with an empty string.

To replace between tags you could have regex like below, but as @Veverke said, you should look into a more robust html minification, as this would not be fool-proof

```
/>(&nbsp;|\s)*</
```